# get whether use daylight saving time in linux c++

Tags: c++

tzset function's variable daylight is obsolete.   my program run in the Los Angeles's server.
I wan't know the good solution to  know whether use dst   (daylight saving time)  in linux c++.

Comment: Are you searching the `localtime` function ? It sets the `tm_isdst` in `struct tm`

Comment: You don't need to know whether DST is in effect. You just need to use the right TZ specification and it will take care of DST. A server probably shouldn't need local time anyway, local time is for user-facing applications.

Comment: I need to send the server time(such as:  time(null) + dst timezone * 3600) to  user-facing applications.

Comment: Send UTC. Your server could be on the moon for all they know.

Comment: I want the user-facing application show the server time.